# Difference between 'gmake' and 'gmake2' actions in premake5

Tags: premake

I am a new user of premake5, and trying to understand how I can use it in future projects. For generators, there is an option for 'gmake' and for 'gmake2', which appear to generate different Makefiles, but I am unclear exactly what the differences are.

I am unable to find much information about it on the wiki, and it does not seem that gmake2 is simply a new and improved version of gmake.

A similar question was asked recently on a [github issue #885](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/885), but without a response. Can anyone inform me on what the differences are, so I will know when to use which?

Comment: gmake is the original makefile generator, gmake2 is a new one provided by Blizzard. It's not clear why it was added since both generate makefiles. The best way to find out would probably be to go to either the Google Group for Premake: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/premake-development or in the referenced issue, ping the author of the gmake2 module (with @tvandijck) In the meantime, just use gmake action, it's well tested.